# Direct upload string to s3 from bootstrap modal not working

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, bootstrap-modal, aws-sdk

I observed a very strange behavior. If I set a button from web to upload string to S3, it works fine. But if I set a button from web to bring up a bootstrap modal, then from this modal I set a button to upload the string, it doesn't work.

Frontend is like below in both cases. The difference is whether clicking to run function 'saveToAWS' from web or from modal as 2-step-process, the latter returns xhr.status as 0.

```
    function saveToAWS() {

  var file = new File([jsonStr], "file.json", { type: "application/json" });

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var fn=file.name;
  var ft = file.type;

  xhr.open("GET", "/sign_s3_save?file-name=" + fn + "&file-type=" + ft);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {

      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log('signiture returned')
        save_file(file, response.signed_request, response.url);
      }
      else {
        alert("Could not get signed URL.");
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
function save_file(file, signed_request, url) {


  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', signed_request);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {

        console.log('200');
      }
      else {
        alert('cannot upload file');            
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(file);
}
```

Backend as Node.js, in order to get a signed URL:

```
app.get('/sign_s3_save', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    var fileName = req.query['file-name'];
    var fileType = req.query['file-type'];

    aws.config.update({ accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY });
    var s3 = new aws.S3();

    var ac = req.user._id;
    var timenow = Date.now().toString();
    var fileRename = ac + '/json/' + timenow + '.json';
    var s3_params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        Key: fileRename,
        Expires: 60,

        ContentType: fileType,
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3_params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            var return_data = {
                signed_request: data,

                url: 'https://' + S3_BUCKET + '.s3.amazonaws.com/' + fileRename
            };

            res.write(JSON.stringify(return_data));
            res.end();
        }
    });
});
```

Any suggestion, please?

Comment: Where is `jsonStr` defined?

Comment: jsonStr is global...but it doesn't matter. I tried static way, such as 'new File(["abcdefg"], "file.json", { type: "application/json" })', still same results: one-step ok, two-steps wrong.

Comment: What do you mean by "two-steps"?

Comment: one-step: button on web to run function 'saveToAWS'. Two-steps: button to show a modal, then a button on modal to run function 'saveToAWS'

Comment: Can you reproduce at jsfiddle https://jsdiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co? Is `jsonStr` still defined at modal?

Comment: But where should I host the Node.js? I am still testing server in local. jsonStr is not a problem. I have tried to change it to static string and it works  or fails the same way.

Comment: nodejs does not appear to be the issue. The modal, or second click, appears to be the issue. You can echo `XMLHttpRequest()` created response at jsfiddle or create separate files at plnkr. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve